# Application.ThreadException not working

Tags: c#, .net

```
   static class Program
   {
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           /* From my understanding this should install the exception handler */
           Application.ThreadException += GetEventHandler();
           /* Since posting this question I have found that I need to add the 
              following line, but even with the following line in place the
              exceptions thrown are not caught.... */
           Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
           /* Some auto generated code here */
           Application.Run(new MyForm());
       }


       private static ThreadExceptionEventHandler GetEventHandler()
       {
           return new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);
       }

       private static void OnThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
       {

           MessageBox.Show("Big error...");

       }
   }
```

According to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
this should work. But when an exception is thrown inside of the `MyForm` class it does not show the "Big error..." message box but tells me that there is no exception handler. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Set the `UnhandleExceptionMode` to `CatchException` it

```
       /* From my understanding this should install the exception handler */
       Application.ThreadException += GetEventHandler();
       Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
       /* Some auto generated code here */
       Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

---

`Application.ThreadException` can only trap exceptions that are raised in the UI thread. In code that's run due to Windows notifications. Or in technical terms, the events that are triggered by the message loop. Most any Winforms event fit this category.

What it does *not* trap are exceptions raised on any non-UI thread, like a worker thread started with `Thread.Start()`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or a delegate's `BeginInvoke()` method.  Any unhandled exception in those will terminate the app.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned since I posted the question I've found that trick and that did not work. It still won't catch any exceptions.

Comment: what code is raising the exception ? and is the exception raised in the UI thread?

Comment: `private void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  throw new Exception("Test Exception..."); }` Inside of the MyForm class.

Comment: Alright, I believe you... I don't know what else is wrong I'll go hunting.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?